# Bootstrap Table in full screen

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am quite new to web application platform. I just want my data table in full screen

[image]

Comment: Please provide samples of your code to give an accurate solution since it is impossible to give a solution with only an image

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to remove any padding and or margins (which are set as standard in bootstrap). Then in the table make sure you are setting the height and width to the page using the vh-x and vw-x classes. This will force the table size to be the same as the viewport.

```
<div class="container p-0 m-0">         
  <table class="table table-dark table-hover vw-100 vh-100">
```

Here is a JS fiddle so you can see what is going on...
https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/hdgbyzn9/18/

Full example code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--HTML5 DOCTYPE-->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Template</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!--viewport for mobile first design-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- CONTAINER -->

    <div class="container p-0 m-0">         
      <table class="table table-dark table-hover vw-100 vh-100">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Useful Docs...
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/

It would be a good idea to share your code in the question to we can help more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table>
        ..........
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello freind..
if i undrestand your question you should try this

Answer (score 0):

You should make your table have `width` at `100%`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use free **BootStrap table**, with option `showFullScreen` to `true`.
It will render a "fullscreen" button that you can toggle.

- [Documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#showfullscreen)
- [Example](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/show-fullscreen.html)